# How to filter records based on specific value in subquery?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, query-optimization

**Scenario:**
I have a table of jobs which I want to fetch. Each job has one or more items associated with it which are stored in jobItems table. item's code and details are saved in items table. There is one-to-many relationship between jobs and jobItems tables. Also keep in mind, it has large dataset.

I want to show all jobs which has one specific item in their jobItems.

**MySQL fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4a5a47

**Schema:**

```
CREATE TABLE jobs (
    `id` INT,
    `jobRef` VARCHAR (55)
);

INSERT INTO jobs (`id`, `jobRef`)
VALUES
    (1, 'job1'),
    (2, 'job2'),
    (3, 'job3');

CREATE TABLE jobItems (
    `id` INT,
    `itemId` INT,
    `jobId` INT
);

INSERT INTO jobItems (`id`, `itemId`, `jobId`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 1),
    (2, 2, 1),
    (3, 3, 1),
    (4, 1, 2),
    (5, 2, 2),
    (6, 3, 3);

CREATE TABLE items (
    `id` INT,
    `itemCode` VARCHAR (55)
);

INSERT INTO items (`id`, `itemCode`)
VALUES
    (1, 'item1'),
    (2, 'item2'),
    (3, 'item3');
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT
    jobs.*, ji.allItems
FROM
    jobs
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        jobItems.jobId,
        GROUP_CONCAT(items.itemCode) AS allItems
    FROM
        jobItems
    INNER JOIN items ON jobItems.itemId = items.id
    GROUP BY
        jobItems.jobId
) AS ji ON ji.jobId = jobs.id
```

As you noticed, there is a LEFT JOIN as well as a GROUP BY on jobItems.jobId which are creating issues in implementing this item based job filter.

**Tried Options:**

- I tried to remove the GROUP BY and GROUP_CONCAT, so it will return
  all the possible job-item combinations. I thought to manipulate them
  using php at backend. But it has one drawback that it disturbs the
  pagination.
- I also tried to dynamically change LEFT JOIN into INNER JOIN and
  inside the subquery, I added a condition on the INNER JOIN INNER JOIN
  items ON jobItems.itemId = items.id AND jobItems.itemId IN (1) But,
  it doesn't fetch desired result because of the GROUP BY as it will
  only return the jobs which have only one item with the given itemId.
  It doesn't return jobs which have multiple items including item with
  itemId= 1.

In short, I want to fetch all jobs which have items containing item with itemId = 1. And expected result is job1 and job2 as they both have item1 in them.

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: @Madhivanan I have edited the question and added expected result in it.

Comment: job3 has item1, FYI

Comment: Job3 also has item1

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen , sorry for that, I have edited the job 3 and corrected its item.

Comment: Now try the code I posted. It will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT jobs.*, ji.allItems
FROM jobs
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        jobItems.jobId,
        GROUP_CONCAT(items.itemCode) AS allItems
    FROM
        jobItems
    INNER JOIN items ON jobItems.itemId = items.id 
    GROUP BY
        jobItems.jobId
    HAVING MAX(CASE WHEN jobItems.itemId = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
) AS ji ON ji.jobId = jobs.id
```

## SQLFiddle

For multiple item filters (for example you want to find jobs associated with both items 1 and 2)

```
SELECT jobs.*, ji.allItems
FROM jobs
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        jobItems.jobId,
        GROUP_CONCAT(items.itemCode) AS allItems
    FROM
        jobItems
    INNER JOIN items ON jobItems.itemId = items.id 
    GROUP BY
        jobItems.jobId
    HAVING 
    MAX(CASE WHEN jobItems.itemId = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
    MAX(CASE WHEN jobItems.itemId = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 
) AS ji ON ji.jobId = jobs.id
```

Comment: This won't work if the min `itemId` happens to be less than one.

Comment: Yes. I modified differently

Comment: Its working. Can we convert it to filter it for multiple items at a time like an IN condition?

Answer (score 0):

Is this work for you.

```
select j.*, i.itemCode from jobs j
inner join jobItems m on m.jobid = j.id
inner join items i on i.id = m.itemId
where exists (select 'x' from jobItems a 
              where a.itemId = 2
              and a.jobId = j.id)
```

Hope you want to get jobs which particular item binded.

Let me to know if i miss understand your requirement.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4a5a47/11

Comment: I also need to display all the items associated of a job, which it will not fetch.

Comment: I have did some changes. please check and let me to know is this work for you

Comment: Its returning jobs multiple times. 1 time for each item

Comment: sorry i think i misunderstand your requirement. can i tell me the result when user select item2 for restriction

Comment: It should return two rows:
(1)  job1  item2,item3,item1
(2)  job2  item2,item1`

Comment: If I add GROUP BY in your query, it will start giving correct results.

Comment: `SELECT
 j.*, GROUP_CONCAT(i.itemCode) as allItems
FROM
 jobs j
INNER JOIN jobItems m ON m.jobid = j.id
INNER JOIN items i ON i.id = m.itemId
WHERE
 EXISTS (
  SELECT
   'x'
  FROM
   jobItems a
  WHERE
   a.itemId = 2
  AND a.jobId = j.id
 )
GROUP BY
 j.id`